# Avro Serialisation using Schema Registry Exception

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Schema on the Registry that has been created by Kafka Connect. I'm also programmatically trying to publish to the Kafka topic pertinent to the Schema (using TopicRecordNameStrategy), using the exact Schema definition as exists on the registry in my Java application, the use-case being republishing delayed messages automatically.

How, therefore, is it possible that by using the exact Schema that already exists, am I thrown the exception:

```
"Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409"
```

The schema is identical, as has been confirmed by JSON comparison

Comment: Please show both schemas

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred when you already have one schema registered in schema registry.
And when you pushed the new message it needs to match with new schema but because older schema has not overridden, you encounter with this error. One way to resolve this issue

**Just delete all the subjects one by one with following command.**

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/<subject_name>
```

Then push the messages.

If your pushed message and schema gets match you'll see the message processed.

**Find subjects :**
http://localhost:8081/subjects/

Comment: If there's a schema created by Kafka Connect already there, then that's going to be used by a source connector. If that's deleted/replaced then it'll break the connector

Comment: @OneCricketeer Could you please elaborate what connector you are talking about ?
Jdbc connector or something else ?

Comment: Any source connector